# how to calculate percentages in geom_flow() based on variable size and not stratum size

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I am trying the create an alluvial plot with `geom_flow()` and display the percentages of the flows. This works, however if I use more than two variables, I noticed that the percentages in the middle columns are smaller than I expected, to be exact they are exactly half of the value I would expect. In the following example you can see that going from `V1` to `V2` the outgoing percentage of values who stayed `A` is 26%, but the incoming percentage in `V2` is 13%. I think it calculates the percentages based on the size of the stratum, which sums up all values from the incoming and outgoing flows and is therefore 200 instead of 100. How can I display percentages based on the variable size and the stratum size?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:100, 3), 
                 value = sample(c("A", "B"), replace = TRUE, 300),
                 variable = rep(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), each = 100),
                 N = 1
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, stratum = value, alluvium = id, y = N, fill = value)) +
  geom_lode() + 
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0) + 
  geom_text(stat = "flow", aes(
    label = scales::percent(after_stat(prop), accuracy = 1),
    hjust = after_stat(flow) == "to"
  ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I know that I could calculate the percentages if I specify the group size when calculating the percentages `label = scales::percent(after_stat(count)/100, accuracy = 1)`, however later on I want to uses facets with different group sizes and therefore I need a solution which calculates the percentages based on the given data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The `prop` computed under the hood does not take the `flow` into account.

One option to fix that would be to manually compute the percentages inside `after_stat()` for which I use `ave`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:100, 3),
  value = sample(c("A", "B"), replace = TRUE, 300),
  variable = rep(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), each = 100),
  N = 1
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = variable, stratum = value, alluvium = id,
  y = N, fill = value
)) +
  geom_lode() +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0) +
  geom_text(stat = "flow", aes(
    label = after_stat(
      scales::percent(
        ave(count, x, flow, group, FUN = sum) /
          ave(count, x, flow, FUN = sum),
        accuracy = 1
      )
    ),
    hjust = after_stat(flow) == "to"
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I prefer this answer, because it works well even if I use facets. The only thing I had to add was `PANEL` as a grouping variable in both `ave()`-functions.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat easier way to do this is to use `after_stat(n)/max(after_stat(ymax))`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, stratum = value, 
               alluvium = id, y = N, fill = value)) +
  geom_lode() + 
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0) + 
  geom_text(stat = "flow", aes(
    label = scales::percent(after_stat(n)/after_stat(max(ymax))),
    hjust = after_stat(flow) == "to"
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: Should have had a look at the documentation. (: And now I'm wondering what's the difference between `count` and `n`. (;